# Javascript template parsing in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, client-side-templating

I have implemented basic template parser for javascript. it simply replaces variables within template string. i.e    {event.date}   will be  7/4/2013

I am using script tag to store template string

```
<script id="date_template" type="text/html"> <span class="date" id="date_{event.id}">  {event.date}  <span> </script>
```

but it gives error in mobile devices so I have used div element for this

```
<div style="display:none" id="date_template"> <span class="date" id="date_{event.id}">  {event.date}  <span> </div>
```

but it creates dom element which causes other problems. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: you can probably create a main container div that will contain all your templates.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: @chumkiu it doesn't take type attribute in account in mobile devices it gives syntax error in template strings

Comment: @RupeshPatel I've no errors with this. Which browser/mobile have you tested?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this:

```
$("<span/>",  
   {
    "class":"date",
    "id":"date_$event.id".replace(/\$event.id/,event.id),
    "html":event.date
   }
 )
```

**References**

- [jquery constructor: jquery(html, attributes)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)